# How do you add a collapsible table like mybb

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a collapsible table like mybb

http://prntscr.com/21e2gq

I tried this on jsfiddle but I could not get this to work in my html file here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BurnedDesigns/hqB5B/

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>The Coding Experts</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/global.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Website coded by Burned Deisgns - The Coding Experts Tutor -->


<div id="container">


    <div id="header">
    <div class="float_right menu">
        <ul class="navigation">

            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home-icon.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>

    </div>


    <div id="content">

<table class="tborder">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="thead"> 

        <a href="#" id="exclo" style="float:right"><img src="images/min.png"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="trow">
            <div id="fliped">Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I could not get this to work" is not the best error description. What is happening that is not supposed to happen? Can you also show us the complete js code on your site? My guess is that you aren't running your code on `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BurnedDesigns/hqB5B/) works fine.   Clicking the Open / Close button will display and hide the "content" section as expected.

In your code on the website, make sure you are wrapping your jQuery script in this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// code here
});
```

This will make sure your code fires when expected.

Comment: Thank you ive solved this issue already but still thank you for the answer though.